# raphael text() not working in ie9

Tags: text, internet-explorer-9, raphael

Why is the following example not working in ie9?

http://jsfiddle.net/dzyyd/2/

It spits out a console error:

> "Unexpected call to method or property access."

Answer (score 1):

I found it pretty quickly.  You created the element, but did not put it anywhere. Once it is added to the document body, everything seems to be fine.

```
this._width=300;
this._height=300;
this._bgSvgContainer = document.createElement("div");
//NOTE: add the created div to the body of the document so that it is displayed
document.body.appendChild(this._bgSvgContainer);
var bgCanvas = Raphael(this._bgSvgContainer, this._width, this._height);
this._bgCanvas = bgCanvas;
var num = this._bgCanvas.text(this._width-10,this._height-10,"1");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell with such a tiny code-fragment (doesn't run on any browser for me), but it's probably a scope issue `this` in IE during events is completely different to `this` using the W3C event model.  See: [quirksmode-Event order](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)-Problems of the Microsoft model